# How to transform tables using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

---I have a csv dataset---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a1','a1','a1','a1','a1','a1'], 'B':['b','b','b','b1','b1','b1','b1','b1','b1'], 'C':['c','c','c','c1','c1','c1','c1','c1','c1'], 'D':['d','d1','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8'], 'Rank':[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6})
```

---I want to transform as in the following table ---

```
 pd.pivot_table(df, values = ['D'] index=['A','B','C'], columns = 'Rank').reset_index()
```

---I didn't get what I want---

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a1'], 'B':['b','b1'], 'C':['c','c1'], '1':['d','d3'], '2':['d1','d4'], '3':['d2','d5'], '4':['NaN','d6'], '5':['NaN','d7'], '6':['NaN','d8'], '7':['NaN','NaN']})
```

Comment: Have you consulted this? => https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html#user-guide

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `pivot`, not `pivot_table` in this case:

```
df.pivot(index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns='Rank', values='D').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Rank   A   B   C   1   2   3    4    5    6
0      a   b   c   d  d1  d2  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     a1  b1  c1  d3  d4  d5   d6   d7   d8
```

`pivot_table` aggregates duplicates, but `pivot` doesn't. Which is what you want.

To remove axis name:

```
df.pivot(index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns='Rank', values='D').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   1   2   3    4    5    6
0   a   b   c   d  d1  d2  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  a1  b1  c1  d3  d4  d5   d6   d7   d8
```